# Get a Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

I get a "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" not sure what I am missing

```
Sub Macro1()


 Dim Lcol As Long

     Dim WS As Worksheets

With WS

 Lcol = WS.Cells(1, WS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Define Last Col

        Range("B18:O18" & Lcol - 2).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=OR(B18>P$18)"
        Range("B18:O18" & Lcol - 2).FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With Range("B18:O18" & Lcol - 2).FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        End With


End With

End Sub
```

Error occurs at `Lcol = WS.Cells(1, WS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Define Last Col`

Comment: You defined `ws` as a worksheets object instead of a worksheet object. And you never told it which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined ws as a worksheets object instead of a worksheet object. And you never told it which one.

change

```
Dim WS As Worksheets
```

to

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = Worksheets(1)
```

That will use the first worksheet. Change the `1` to another index, or specify it by name, like this:

```
Set WS = Worksheets("Sheet1")
```